# How can I copy a field to another field?

Tags: nodes, 10

I have an *Article* content type for which I want to change the machine name of its fields. I created new fields with a different machine name.

How do I copy the old fields to the new fields?

Answer (score 2):

You can run this, in [hook_update_N()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Extension%21module.api.php/function/hook_update_N/10):

```php
$storage = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node');
// Load all the nodes IDs for nodes that don't have the new value set.
$nids = $storage->getQuery()
  // Load all nodes for which the new field has no value.
  ->notExists('new_field_name')
  ->execute();

// Loop through the nodes.
foreach ($nids as $nid) {
  // Load the current node.
  $node = $storage->load($nid);
  // Set the new field name to the old field name and save.
  $node->set('new_field_name', $node->get('old_field_name')->value)
    ->save();
}
```